# Header or something to add to a code to detect if folder exist

Tags: c++, directory, mingw-w64

I search to test if a folder exists. I have found the following code in the question:
[Check folder path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6252060/check-folder-path)

```
bool directory_exists( const std::string &directory )
    {
    if( !directory.empty() )
        {
        if( access(directory.c_str(), 0) == 0 )
            {
            struct stat status;
            stat( directory.c_str(), &status );
            if( status.st_mode & S_IFDIR )
                return true;
            }
        }
     // if any condition fails
    return false;
    }
```

I have search code with "access" but most of time I found things about mysql because access have this meaning :s.

I use this line to compile:

```
i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -c -O2 -I.-I/usr/win32/include -g  main.cpp -o main.o
```

the errors

```
main.cpp: In function 'bool directory_exists(const string&)':
main.cpp:111:40: erreur: 'access' was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:114:46: erreur: no matching function for call to 'stat::stat(const char*, stat*)'
main.cpp:114:46: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/wchar.h:380:0,
             from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.3/include/c++/cwchar:46,
             from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.3/include/c++/bits/postypes.h:42,
             from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.3/include/c++/iosfwd:42,
             from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.3/include/c++/ios:39,
             from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.3/include/c++/ostream:40,
             from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.3/include/c++/iostream:40,
```

I suppose that I have to add something. A Header?

Comment: What are you headers? Did you included #include <dirent.h>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the 2 following headers:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
```